# Do we have an universal approximation theory on ReLU activated Neural Networks already?

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory, neural-networks

In 1990s several researchers(Hornik, Cybenko, etc.) have proved that feedforward neural networks with **bounded** and **non-constant** activation function are able to approximate any $L_p$-Integrable function.
However many popular activation functions today, ReLU for example, doesn't satisfy the bounded prerequisite.
Is there any theory on approximation capability of neural networks with ReLU as activation function yet?

Comment: See this paper for universality results for much more general activation functions: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0893608005801315 Regarding approximation in Sobolev spaces (of order less than 1), see maybe this paper: https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=de&user=BeMTlIsAAAAJ&citation_for_view=BeMTlIsAAAAJ:LkGwnXOMwfcC

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a node activation such as $$n(x)=\cases{0& if $x<0$\\x& if $0\leq x\leq 1$\\1& otherwise}$$ with two ReLU nodes $n_1,n_2$ like so:
$$
n(x)=n_1(x)-n_2(x-1)
$$
So anything that can be done with the activation $n$ can be exactly replicated with ReLU, and at most twice as many nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It makes sense to me. However, due to its piecewise differentiable nature, it seems like ReLU(or other piecewise differentiable functions) activated NNs don't exhibit a universal approximation ability in Sobolev space.